# Firebase Cloud Functions: `convert` is failing with ChildProcessError

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, imagemagick-convert

I am using Firebase Cloud function to auto generate thumbnails of uploaded Images.

I followed the Sample code @ https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/generate-thumbnail

and made this file:

```
"use strict";

const functions                 =   require("firebase-functions");
const mkdirp                    =   require("mkdirp-promise");
const gcs                       =   require("@google-cloud/storage")({keyFilename: functions.config().env.serviceaccount});
//const admin                     =   require("firebase-admin");
const spawn                     =   require("child-process-promise").spawn;
const path                      =   require("path");
const os                        =   require("os");
const fs                        =   require("fs");

// Max height and width of the thumb8ail in pixels.
const _800_MAX_WIDTH            =   800;
const _800_MAX_HEIGHT           =   800;
const _400_MAX_WIDTH            =   400;
const _400_MAX_HEIGHT           =   400;
const _100_MAX_WIDTH            =   100;
const _100_MAX_HEIGHT           =   100;

// Thumbnail prefix added to file names.
//const ORIGINAL_PREFIX           =   "original_";
const _800_PREFIX               =   "800_";
const _400_PREFIX               =   "400_";
const _100_PREFIX               =   "100_";

/**
 * When an image is uploaded in the Storage bucket We generate a thumbnail automatically using
 * ImageMagick.
 * After the thumbnail has been generated and uploaded to Cloud Storage,
 * we write the public URL to the Firebase Realtime Database.
 */
export const generateThumbnail  =   functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
    const filePath              =   event.data.name;
    const fileDir               =   path.dirname(filePath);
    const fileName              =   path.basename(filePath);
    const filePath800           =   path.normalize(path.join(fileDir, `${_800_PREFIX}${fileName}`));
    const filePath400           =   path.normalize(path.join(fileDir, `${_400_PREFIX}${fileName}`));
    const filePath100           =   path.normalize(path.join(fileDir, `${_100_PREFIX}${fileName}`));
    const tempLocalFile         =   path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
    //const tempLocalFile800      =   path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath800);
    //const tempLocalFile400      =   path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath400);
    //const tempLocalFile100      =   path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath100);
    const tempLocalDir          =   path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
    const tempLocal800File      =   path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath800);
    const tempLocal400File      =   path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath400);
    const tempLocal100File      =   path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath100);

    // Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
    if (!event.data.contentType.startsWith("image/")) {
        console.log("This is not an image.");
        return;
    }

    // Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.
    if (fileName.startsWith(_800_PREFIX) || fileName.startsWith(_400_PREFIX) || fileName.startsWith(_100_PREFIX)) {
        console.log("Already a Thumbnail.");
        return;
    }

    // Exit if this is a move or deletion event.
    if (event.data.resourceState === "not_exists") {
        console.log("This is a deletion event.");
        return;
    }

    // Cloud Storage files.
    const bucket = gcs.bucket(event.data.bucket);
    const file = bucket.file(filePath);
    //const file800 = bucket.file(filePath800);
    //const file400 = bucket.file(filePath400);
    //const file100 = bucket.file(filePath100);

    // Create the temp directory where the storage file will be downloaded.
    return mkdirp(tempLocalDir).then(() => {
        // Download file from bucket.
        return file.download({destination: tempLocalFile});
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("The file has been downloaded to", tempLocalFile);
        // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
        return Promise.all([
            spawn("convert", [tempLocalFile, "-thumbnail", `${_800_MAX_WIDTH}x${_800_MAX_HEIGHT}>`, tempLocal800File], {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']}),
            spawn("convert", [tempLocalFile, "-thumbnail", `${_400_MAX_WIDTH}x${_400_MAX_HEIGHT}>`, tempLocal400File], {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']}),
            spawn("convert", [tempLocalFile, "-thumbnail", `${_100_MAX_WIDTH}x${_100_MAX_HEIGHT}>`, tempLocal100File], {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']})
        ]);
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("Thumbnail created at", tempLocal800File, tempLocal400File, tempLocal100File);
        // Uploading the Thumbnail.
        return Promise.all([
            bucket.upload(tempLocal800File, {destination: filePath800}),
            bucket.upload(tempLocal400File, {destination: filePath400}),
            bucket.upload(tempLocal100File, {destination: filePath100}),
        ]);
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("Thumbnail uploaded to Storage at", filePath800, filePath400, filePath100);
        // Once the image has been uploaded delete the local files to free up disk space.
        fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
        fs.unlinkSync(tempLocal800File);
        fs.unlinkSync(tempLocal400File);
        fs.unlinkSync(tempLocal100File);

        return true;
    });

});
```

The code was working good all these days. But recently the code started throwing this error:

```
ChildProcessError: `convert /tmp/gr/regionalData/in/31/3100/ngo/-Kz3c8teLyPWZGzRLdKD/-LEEop6Wvet4Aj1ybP-T.jpg -thumbnail 400x400> /tmp/gr/regionalData/in/31/3100/ngo/-Kz3c8teLyPWZGzRLdKD/400_-LEEop6Wvet4Aj1ybP-T.jpg` failed with code 1
```

I tried re-deploying, but no use. Any hints on where to start looking for cause of the problem?

Comment: Did you upgrade to ImageMagick 7? If so, the convert is replaced with magick. You could also try -thumbnail "400x400>". Is your /tmp directory full or nearly full? Have permissions changed on /tmp?

Comment: @fmw42 I deploy to Firebase cloud. So not sure what version of ImageMagick they run. Is there any way to know, through some log commands? Same goes with other Qs on is /tmp full or any permissions changed. Couldn't answer as everything happens within Google Cloud

Comment: If you can issue terminal command, then `convert -version` or `magick -version` will tell you the ImageMagick version depending upon whether IM 6 or IM 7. Also `cd /tmp` and `ls -al` will show you what you have in your /tmp directory. I generally do not recommend processing imagemagick with images in the /tmp directory, because imagemagick creates temp file there. So if you put your input and output images there you could exceed potential limits. Might you have changed imagemagick versions to ImageMagick 7? `which convert` or `which magick` may be able to tell you that.

Comment: Hi. Appreciate your support. I am a basic linux user myself, but I dont think we can run commands in Firebase cloud server. We dont have terminal/SSH access to it. That's the problem!

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about Firebase cloud and how to use it to find out about ImageMagick. Check if Firebase cloud had an upgrade that you did not know about. Perhaps they switched imagemagick versions or some other thing that might affect your processing.